# Удаление экземпляра класса в методе __init__ - Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, конструктор, деструктор

Есть класс `Foo`:

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, data = None):
        if data == None:
            self.__del__()

    def __del__(self):
        print('Error')

f = Foo()    # Error
print(f)     # <__main__.Foo object at 0x7fc1210de1d0>
```

У меня такая проблема:

Если создаётся экземпляр класса, мне нужно проверить, передан ли аргумент `data`. Если нет, создание класса нужно отменить. Я вызываю из метода `__init__` метод `__del__`, но экземпляр остаётся в памяти, это можно проверить с помощью `print(f)`. Уже когда-то это делал, может, что-то забыл, но совсем не понимаю: как фиксить и что гуглить?

Comment: Удалить уже созданный экземпляр класса самостоятельно невозможно. Функция `__del__` это обычная функция (ну или метод, если угодно) и она ничего не значит (в некоторых реализациях Python она не используется вообще никак). Единственное, что можно сделать — выбросить исключение в `__init__` и надеяться, что однажды за созданным экземпляром класса придёт сборщик мусора и удалит его (а в некоторых реализациях он может и не прийти)

Comment: @andreymal, что-то мне сомнительно, что исключение в `__init__` может на что-то повлиять... Насколько я помню, к моменту, когда вызывается `__init__`, экземпляр уже создан. Возможно, манипуляции с `__new__` могут помочь.

Comment: @Александр да, потому я и написал про сборщик мусора. `__new__` возможно, но я с ним очень мало работал, не знаю

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Имхо, нужно не удалять уже созданный экземпляр, а просто не создавать его. Созданием управляет метод `__new__`, который срабатывает до `__init__`, и получает на вход те же аргументы, что и он. Метод `__new__` должен создать и вернуть свеженький экземпляр класса. Соответственно, можно попробовать переопределить этот метод так, чтобы он в определённых случаях ничего не создавал.

```
class Foo:

    def __new__(cls, data=None):
        if data is None:
            print('Error')
            return None
        else:
            return super().__new__(cls)


f1 = Foo()    # Error
print(f1)     # None

f2 = Foo('some data')
print(f2)     # <__main__.Foo object at 0x7f3e5fb22a90>
```

Comment: То, что мне нужно. Спасибо.